# Simple JS function. Needing clarification on a variable

Tags: javascript, function

So I was reading the book, "Eloquent Javascript" today, and as with every example they bring to me, I try to study and observe it. I came across this function and I cannot figure out why the variable "result" is needed. All I know is that if it is not in the function, the function output doesn't work. I am having trouble understanding why? Could someone take a quick look at it for me?

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == undefined)
    exponent = 2;
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If "result" isn't in the function, there's no variable to return, so what would you possibly expect it to do? There *isn't* a variable called "results"...

Comment: The purpose of the `power` function is to compute something. `result` is used to store the (intermediate) result of the operation. How would you do it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the function recursively, you don't need the intermediate result

```
function power(base, exponent, value) {
  value = value || 1;

  // assumes exponent of 0 if none provided. n^0 = 1.
  if (!exponent)
    return value;

  return power (base, exponent - 1, value * base);
}

power(2, 3) // 8
power(9) // 1, since 9^0 is 1
```

to make it deal with negative exponents, you could also try this:

```
function power(base, exponent, value) {
    value = value || 1;

    // assumes exponent of 0 if none provided. n^0 = 1.
    if (exponent == 0) return value;
    if (exponent < 1) return (1 / power(base, -1 * exponent, value));

    return power (base, exponent - 1, value * base);
}
```